# What is the proper function for comparing two C-style strings?

Tags: c++, c, string, compare

So I have a dilemma. I need to compare two C-style strings and I searched for the functions that would be the most appropiate:

```
memcmp   //Compare two blocks of memory (function)
strcmp   //Compare two strings (function )
strcoll  //Compare two strings using locale (function)
strncmp  //Compare characters of two strings (function)
strxfrm  //Transform string using locale (function)
```

The first one I think is for addresses, so the idea is out. 
The second one sounds like the best choice to me, but I wanna hear feedback anyway.
The other three leave me clueless.

Comment: *"The first one I think is for addresses"* - No, it's for arbitrary blocks of memory. In the end all of those functions take addresses pointing to the memory blocks to be compared. But none actually compares addresses. But from your in-code comments I guess you are aware of this and just expressed yourself a bit inaccurately.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For general string comparisons, `strcmp` is the appropriate function.  You should use `strncmp` to only compare some number of characters from a string (for example, a prefix), and `memcmp` to compare blocks of memory.

That said, since you're using C++, you should avoid this altogether and use the `std::string` class, which is much easier to use and generally safer than C-style strings.  You can compare two `std::string`s for equality easily by just using the `==` operator.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I'd love to, but for now our professor is restricting us to just use C Strings.

Comment: Check for the C plus function code and read it... maybe you would find a surprise., and @templatetypedef i think that == is not the rite operator in this case imho.

Comment: @ingcarlos- You are correct that you shouldn't use == here.  My suggestion is to switch to C++'s std::string, in which case the == operator is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Both `memcmp` and `strcmp` will work fine.  To use the former, you'll need to know the length of the shorter string in advance.

Comment: If you call `memcmp` with the length of the former string, then it will tell you that `"abc"` and `"abcdef"` are equal.  You could pass it the length of the shorter string plus one (and it will see and compare the `'\0'` terminator)  -- but since `strcmp` is specifically designed to compare strings, that's what you should use.

Comment: I'd agree with all of that, yup.

Comment: Anyone know if `memcmp` can be faster, say due to knowing the length in advance and hence allowing some optimisation by looking at word length chunks in the first instance?

Comment: @Keith: Maybe, maybe not. Trust your runtime library and use the function that *means* what you want. Don't try to outsmart the compiler.