# Comparing two char* for equality

Tags: c++, c-strings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the proper function for comparing two C-style strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122000/what-is-the-proper-function-for-comparing-two-c-style-strings)

My match condition doesn't work! Can someone advise how to compare to C-style strings?

```
void saveData(string line, char* data){
    char *testString = new char[800];
    char *stpr;
    int i=0;
    bool isData=false;
    char *com = data;
    strcpy(testString,line.c_str());
        stpr = strtok(testString, ",");
        while (stpr != NULL) {
            string temp = stpr;
            cout << temp << " ===== " << data << endl;
```

Even though `temp` and `data` match, the following condition doesn't work:

```
if (stpr==data) {
  isData = true; 
}
```

Not sure if this helps. The `SaveData()` function is called from the function below:

```
void readFile(char* str){
    string c="", line, fileName="result.txt", data(str);
        ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(fileName.c_str());
    resultlist.clear();

    if(inFile.good()){    
        while(!inFile.eof()){
            getline(inFile, line);
            if(line.find(data)!=string::npos){
                cout << line << endl;
            }
            saveData(line, str);
        }
        inFile.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, its my mistake. It is comparing 2 char*

Answer (score 33):

Since both `stpr` and `data` are C strings, you need to use [`strcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp):

```
#include <string.h>
...
if (strcmp(stpr, data) == 0) {
    // strings are equal
    ...
} else {
    // strings are NOT equal
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still not able to enter the condition. @NPE

Comment: C++ header 'string.h' is deprecated. consider using 'cstring' instead

Answer (score 5):

This condition wont work because the `==` operator is not overloaded for `char*`.

```
if(stpr==data)
{ 
  isData = true; 
}
```

Use this instead.

```
if (strcmp(stpr, data) == 0)
{
  isData = true ;
}
```

[`strcmp()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) returns `0` if both the cstrings are equal. Make sure that both the cstrings you are matching hold some legal memory and are null terminated at the end.

Edit:

To avoid any sort of hassle and bugs, it is advisable not to use raw `char*` and use `std::string` instead. So better make them strings and compare them.

```
std::string data ;   //passed or declared as string
std::string stpr ;
.....
//Do some work.

if (stpr == data)
   //do work here
```

This approach would save you a lot of troubles.

Comment: `0 == strcmp` looks a bit more explicit than `!strcmp` IMHO

Comment: Yes you are right. Old practices seldom fade away. :)

Comment: Hi @Coding Mash, 
I am still not able to enter the condition even when 2 chars are the same. Could the type or stm relates to this error?

Comment: Are both the cstrings allocated some memory and are null terminated?

Comment: @CodingMash you could see that I can cout both temp and data before I make the comparision

Comment: Post some more code, and from where the function is called. There would be some issue there

Comment: can I actually conver Char* to string and then compare string and string?

Comment: @CodingMash please advise from the edited code

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to compare two char*. YOu can try using `strcmp(stpr, data)` for checking the conditions.

Better use it like

```
 if(strcmp(stpr, data)==0){..}
```