# comparing what two pointers point to

Tags: c++, pointers, comparison

I'm writing a program to detect phishing. I'm trying to check if the base of the URL, if it is same in the tag or not. 
For e.g. in http://maps.google.com"> www.maps.yahoo.com 
 I'm trying to check if the last 2 parts of the URL are same or not, i.e. if google.com = yahoo.com or not.

I'm using the following code to do so:

```
void checkBase(char *add1, char *add2){
    char *base1[100], *base2[100];
    int count1 = 0, count2 = 0;
    base1[count1] = strtok(add1, ".");
        while(base1[count1] != NULL){
         count1++;
         base1[count1] = strtok(NULL, ".");
    }
    base2[count2] = strtok(add2, ".");
    while(base2[count2] != NULL){
    count2++;
    base2[count2] = strtok(NULL, ".");
    }
    if((base1[count1-1] != base2[count2-1]) && (base1[count1-2] != base2[count2-2])){
         cout << "Bases do not match: " << endl
          << base1[count1-2] << "." << base1[count1-1] << " and "
          << base2[count2-2] << "." << base2[count2-1] << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Bases match: " << endl
              << base1[count1-2] << "." << base1[count1-1] << " and "
                  << base2[count2-2] << "." << base2[count2-1] << endl;

    }
 }
```

I'm not sure if i'm comparison in the if statement is right or not. I'm passing in two URL's.
Thanks

Comment: Aren't there libraries for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the proper function for comparing two C-style strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122000/what-is-the-proper-function-for-comparing-two-c-style-strings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is comparing the two pointers **char*** (as you point out;) )

```
base1[count1-1] != base2[count2-1])
```

use this instead

```
strcmp(base1[count1-1], base2[count2-1]) != 0
```

you could use **std:string** and **boost tokenizer** (now C++11 I think)

regards

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare strings by comparing their addresses, two identical strings can be stored in different addresses. To compare them you should you strcmp:

```
 if(strcmp(base1[count1-1], base2[count2-1]) != 0 || 
    strcmp(base1[count1-2], base2[count2-2])!=0){
        std::cout << "Bases do not match: " << std::endl
            << base1[count1-2] << "." << base1[count1-1] << " and "
            << base2[count2-2] << "." << base2[count2-1] << std::endl;
    }
```

You can do similar with C++ tools:

```
void checkBase(std::string a1, std::string a2){
    size_t a1_start = a1.rfind('.'), a2_start = a2.rfind('.');
    a1_start = a1.rfind('.', a1_start-1);
    a2_start = a2.rfind('.', a2_start-1);
    std::string h1 = a1.substr(a1_start+1), h2 = a2.substr(a2_start+1);
    if (h1 == h2)
        std::cout << "same" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "not same" << std::endl;
}
```