# comparing char buffer to string not working

Tags: c++, string, char, compare

When trying to compare a char buffer to a std string in an if statement it's not working as intended
Here is the code

```
if (ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) != FALSE)   // wait for someone to connect to the pipe
    {
        while (ReadFile(hPipe, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, &dwRead, NULL) != FALSE)
        {
            /* add terminating zero */
            buffer[dwRead] = 0x00;

            /* do something with data in buffer */
            printf("%s\n", buffer);
            
            string cmd = bufferToString(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

            printf("%s", cmd.c_str());

            if (cmd.c_str() == "help") //HERE is the issue
            {
                printf("hello");
            }

        }
    }
```

When comparing it doesn't work
I've tried using different types of conversions of char buffer[1024] to a string but not getting anywhere

EDIT:
I've tried so far

```
    cmd.resize(dwRead);
if (cmd == string("help"))
```

and

```
if (0 == ::std::strcmp(buffer, "help"))
```

none of them work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper function for comparing two C-style strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122000/what-is-the-proper-function-for-comparing-two-c-style-strings) See also: [C++ Compare char array with string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1330550/2602718)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reading the data into a `char[]` and then copying that data into a `std::string`, you could use a `std::string` directly.

Building blocks:

```
std::string cmd;

cmd.resize(wanted_buffer_size); // Set the proper buffer size

ReadFile(hPipe, cmd.data(), cmd.size(), &dwRead, nullptr); // Read directly into cmd

cmd.resize(dwRead); // Shrink down to dwRead afterwards. Automatically null terminated.
```

Comment: Thank you very much I'm new to strings and chars in c++ and this has helped a ton

Comment: @DavidTheTech Glad to hear it! You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You are creating string copying `sizeof(buffer)` characters while it only contains `dwRead` of initialized characters.

Then you compare two pointers instead of string content (which still won't work because `cmd` has wrong length). You should actually compare using `strcmp` without creating temporary `std::string` object.

```
if (0 == ::std::strcmp(buffer, "help"))
{
    printf("hello");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should either do

```
cmd.resize(dwRead);
```

This will set the string to the length of the actual read data, instead of the whole buffer. A c++ `std::string` can contain any data , including `0-bytes`.

Or you  must call

```
string cmd = bufferToString(buffer, dwRead);
```

Which should have the same effect (without seeing the implementation of `bufferToString`).

Also your comparison is wrong. In c++ you would do

```
if (cmd == "help")
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
if (cmd == string("help")) // should work
{
    printf("hello");
}
```

The code:

```
if (cmd.c_str() == "help")
```

will compare pointers (#1 returned from cmd.c_str() , #2 - constant pointer to "help"), that is not quite correct